# PHP sending GET request through email securely

Tags: php, get

I am trying to make an attendance system where I mark the employee's attendance the link is clicked by me. So whenever the employee presses the button, I get an email with their info with a decline and accept URLs. The URLs I'm trying to pass on will have variable data in it, something like:

```
http://website.com/page.php?id=123&username=abc
```

and then use `$_GET['id],` `$_GET['username'].` But the problem that I see with it is that a user could just pass on their information to do the process that I want to do here if they know the URL and their `ID`.

Is there a more secure and better way to do this?

Comment: Hi, haven't you thought about POST method?

Comment: Yeah @D.Khumoyun is right you can use post method

Comment: Use POST method along with login and SESSION concept, like without login user can not hit this URL for attendence. And then no matter what id,name came through Url, do always attendance for logged-in user only.

Comment: I do use POST method to pass user input for validation, and after validation, this information was sent through email for the admin to validate it. But I will use an admin flag to validate it as suggested in the answers. Thank you guys for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is

*if that link is clicked by user , you dont need that param . Store that in session instead and check with that !*

***Or for admin , there is no a problem with that param .You just need to check current user session have admin role or if not just show permission error***

Comment: Thank you. The admin flag validation is exactly what I needed. I don't know why I didn't think of it before.

Comment: Great ! I have developed such a attendance system before :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope you know the post method.Which is works like a letter we post. You cant see what in it until you open it. So use POST method.You can do something like this.In here I assume that user get signed in to the system and then via session user data will be fetched and stored. Then they will be assign into hidden input fields.

```
 <?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['UserName'])) {
    ?>
<form action="http://website.com/page.php" method="post">
<input type="text" value="<?=($_SESSION['UserName']);?>"  name="username" hidden>
<input type="text" value="<?=($_SESSION['UserId']);?>" name="userid"  hidden>
<button type="submit" name="submit">Confirm Your attendance</button>
</form>
<?php
}else{
    header('Location: login.php');
}
```

Comment: Hi. I know about post method, but how can I send this information to an email? So what is going on right now is that when the form is submitted, which is a POST method, it goes to the processing page where all the information is validated, and then it is sent to the manager for approval. The manager gets to click on the link FROM email which redirects him to another processing page. How can I use POST in that?